# Directory listing for one folder htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, directory-listing

I've a folder structure like:

```
        home
         |
snippets---other----bla
   |        |        |
a--b--c   d--e--f  g--h--i
|  |  |   |  |  |  |  |  |
filesfilesfilesfilesfilesfiles
```

I've default files (index.html) in most folders, but for the folders without default files, I used "Options -Indexes" in the home .htaccess to generate a 403 error. In the snippets folder, I use custom directory listing.

```
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options +Indexes
    IndexOptions IgnoreCase VersionSort SuppressHTMLPreamble
    ReadmeName ../index_end.html
    HeaderName ../index_begin.html
</IfModule>
```

Inside the snippets folder Options +Indexes rules. However, I want to prevent directory listing in folder a,b,c. Is there a solution which doesn't needs an htaccess file for every folder? I only have access to htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have access to the httpd.conf file or your virtual host configuration, You can add Directory sections with Wildcards, or [DirectoryMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directorymatch) sections to accomplish this in your httpd.conf file. You're probably looking for something akin to:

```
<Directory /home/snippets/*>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Make sure you read up on how various configuration settings are [merged](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/sections.html#mergin).

Comment: I only have access to .htaccess ):

Comment: With only .htaccess available, sadly I don't know of a better way. You might be able to use symlinks or hard-links so that you only have to write it once and have the same .htaccess in each folder, but that working is dependant on the server configuration.